# Change the one progress bar when its corresponding input filed is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently for both , when one of the input field's value change, two progress bar will change. Can i only change the one progress bar when its corresponding input filed is changed?

```js
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
    var value = this.value;
   var bar = 
    $('.progress-bar')
        .css('width', value+'%')
        .attr('aria-valuenow', value);    
}).keyup();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<td>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control"/>    
</div>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"
         role="progressbar" 
         aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" 
         aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
</td>

<td></td>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control"/>    
</div>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"
         role="progressbar" 
         aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" 
         aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: You are using a class selector - of course both bars will change. Either use two different class selectors, or use IDs.

Comment: You can add custom attribute to your input fields specifying which progress bar should be changed - see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `$('.progress-bar')`, you select all `.progress-bar` element.

Instead, you need to go up one level to the parent, go to the next sibling, and find progress bar there:

Change

```
$('.progress-bar')
```

To:

```
$(this).parent().next('.progress').find('.progress-bar')
```

Al togehter:

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
    var value = this.value;
   var bar = 
    $(this).parent().next('.progress').find('.progress-bar')
        .css('width', value+'%')
        .attr('aria-valuenow', value);    
}).keyup();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the parent element that wraps both and set it as a "namespace" to look for progress bar. Just make sure your HTML markup is valid, as in your example you have missing code for `<table>`,`<tr>` and your `<td>`'s are missplaced as well.

```js
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
    var value = this.value;
    var wrappingTd = $(this).parent().parent();
     
    $(' .progress-bar',wrappingTd)
        .css('width', value+'%')
        .attr('aria-valuenow', value);    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.3/js/tether.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table><tr>    
<td>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text"   class="form-control"/>    
</div>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"
         role="progressbar" 
         aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" 
         aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
</td>

<td> 
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text"   class="form-control"/>    
</div>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"
         role="progressbar" 
         aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" 
         aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: What if the no of input  is unknown , as it depends on the no of database row, so cant hardcoded id for each row

Answer (score 0):

You could assign IDs to each and use the corresponding jQuery ID selector. Like this:

```js
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
    var value = this.value;
   var bar = 
    $('#progress-bar-1')
        .css('width', value+'%')
        .attr('aria-valuenow', value);    
}).keyup();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<td>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control"/>    
</div>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"
         id="progress-bar-1"
         role="progressbar" 
         aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" 
         aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
</td>

<td></td>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control"/>    
</div>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"
         id="progress-bar-2"
         role="progressbar" 
         aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" 
         aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: What if the no of td is unknown , as it depends on the no of database row, so cant hardcoded id for each row